# Can I detect from which mode (EL1, EL0,...) SError interrupt was caused?

Tags: interrupt, arm64

As I know there are separate vectors to handle SError caused by EL0 and EL1.

My queston is follow:

Due to fact that SError is asynchronous, can I rely on fact that if cpu entered **serror_el1_vector** to handle SError, then SError was caused exactly in EL1 (not in EL0, EL2, EL3) and if cpu entered **serror_el0_vector** then SError was exactly caused in EL0? Another word, is it possible folowing case:

1. EL0:

1.1. incorrect access to some device register (for ex. write to RO register) that cause SError interrupt. Such access does not generate access error immediately, but at some point later when AXI transaction actually happened the memory system returns a fault, which is reported as asynchronous abort.

1.2. SError still not generated and user has time to make **svc** to enter EL1

2. EL1:

2.1. Now cpu in EL1  mode enetered by step 1.2

2.2. SError caused by step 1.1 finally generated but now cpu in EL1, not in EL0, so in which vector cpu will enter to handle SError: **serror_el1_vector** or **serror_el0_vector**? Because initially incorrect access was caused in EL0 but now cpu in EL1 state.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I detect from which mode (EL1, EL0,…) SError interrupt was caused?

No, unless you have stronger guarantees than those given in the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/da/DDI0487D_a_armv8_arm.pdf).
The problem is that nearly everything is implementation defined.

For a start, there seems to be no guarantee that an SError is even caused by the PE. Page D1-2198:

> An External abort generated by the memory system might be taken asynchronously using the SError interrupt. These SError interrupts always behave as edge-triggered interrupts. An implementation might include other sources of SError interrupt.

So it's entirely possible that the source of SError can be off-chip.
In addition, in a multi-core system nothing seems to prevent the possibility of core 1 to issue a write that leads to a SError which is subsequently sent to core 2.

Next, let's look at what information an SError carries. Page D1-2170:

> If the exception is a synchronous exception or an SError interrupt, information characterizing the reason for the exception is saved in the ESR_ELx at the target Exception level.

Looking at `ESR_EL1` on page D12-2798:

> IDS, bit [24]
>   IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED syndrome. Possible values of this bit are:
>
> - 0b0
>     Bits[23:0] of the ISS field holds the fields described in this encoding.
>     ---------- Note ----------
>     If the RAS Extension is not implemented, this means that bits[23:0] of the ISS field are RES0.
>     --------------------------
> - 0b1
>     Bits[23:0] of the ISS field holds IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED syndrome information that can be used to provide additional information about the SError interrupt.

So it's possible for the PE to implement a custom register configuration that provides the information you're looking for, but again: that's implementation defined.

Also this is outside of the scope of the PE specification, but it's possible that the memory system provides a way to recover the source of a SError.

Bottom line: Everything's implementation defined, so refer to the manual of your specific hardware.